# Removing unwanted quotes php

Tags: php, laravel, double-quotes, single-quotes

I have two string inputs that are presented in my script iteratively script a while loop:

```
<code>$odometerBrand=PREVIOUS ONC"ODOMETER BRAND"; </code>

<code>$odometerBrand=PREVIOUS ONC'ODOMETER BRAND"</code>
```

I attempt to wrap them with my own quotations but it breaks on one or the other, because of the internal quotations the string values have.

```
<code>
 array_push($actualInventoryArray,array("'".$OdometerBrand)."'" ));
</code>
```

So I Know that the above code doesn't work, because when interested in the database the second value look like:

' PREVIOUS ONC' ODOMETER BRAND" ';   or something worse.

Now how would I go about to remove the quotation marks to insert it into the database?

Comment: $actualInventoryArray[] = array("'". str_replace('"', "'", $OdometerBrand))."'" );`

Comment: have you tried `"\"escaping\""`? also: **use parameterized statements** - they prevent your problem alltogether while protecting you from **sql injections** - *never* insert data into queries by concatenation!

Comment: Yeah I actually tried the built in function for php addslashes(), but it seems as though php doesn't recognize the data as a string at all. because the string comes in with interanl quotation marks. So entire thing :[   This string ' Hello Again"    ] should be a string but no matter what I cannot get the whole data as a string it is either the first two words or last two word recognized

Comment: it's unclear for me what are you trying to achieve. if you want to assign value to variable then yes, escaping should work. As well as [here-doc](http://php.net/heredoc) and [now-doc](http://php.net/nowdoc) syntax form that also makes easier to input new lines.

Answer (score -1):

```
 <code>
       $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=","root","");
    $database= $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO * VALUES ()  ...NOW()")

    //  * = yourtablename( columns names, ""  , "" , "" );

    $database->execute( 
    array_push($actualInventoryArray,array("'".$OdometerBrand)."'" ));
  //you have to make a new pdo statement

 </code>
```